# Error in mocking setState in jest(Argument of type '(init: any) => any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => [unknown, Dispatch<unknown>]')

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, enzyme, setstate

```
const useStateSpy = jest.spyOn(React, 'useState');
useStateSpy.mockImplementation((init) => [init, setState]);
```

##Getting error---Argument of type '(init: any) => any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => [unknown, Dispatch]')##

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please don't mock `useState`, you will break its function.